# Problems displaying input data into a textbox using tkinter,python

Tags: python, input, tkinter, interface, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create a program where you input data directly into the tkinter interface and then displaying the data in a textbox. However, I am getting the following error

```
line 2122, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-textvariable"
```

---

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def textMethod(*args):
    copytext = textinput1.get()
    textoutput1.set(copytext)

root = Tk()

root.title("Naynt Music Database")
frame = ttk.Frame(root,padding = "12 12 12 12")
frame.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky="N,S,E,W")
frame.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

textinput1 = StringVar()
textoutput1 = StringVar()

text_entry = ttk.Entry(frame,width=20,textvariable = textinput1)
text_entry.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=(W,E))
ttk.Button(frame,text="Add songname",command=textMethod).grid(column=1,row=1)

songListFrame = Frame(frame, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)

frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

xscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E+W)

yscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
yscrollbar.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=N+S)

songList = Text(frame, wrap=NONE, bd=0,
            xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
            yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set,
            textvariable=textoutput1)

songList.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

xscrollbar.config(command=songList.xview)
yscrollbar.config(command=songList.yview)

frame.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs because of the lines -

```
songList = Text(frame, wrap=NONE, bd=0,
        xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
        yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set,
        textvariable=textoutput1)
```

You cannot set `textvariable` for `Text` widget .

You should rather use `Text.insert()` method with `END` to insert your songs to the end in the `Text` widget. Example -

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def textMethod(*args):
    copytext = textinput1.get()
    songList.insert(END, copytext + '\n')

root = Tk()

root.title("Naynt Music Database")
frame = ttk.Frame(root,padding = "12 12 12 12")
frame.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky="N,S,E,W")
frame.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

textinput1 = StringVar()
textoutput1 = StringVar()

text_entry = ttk.Entry(frame,width=20,textvariable = textinput1)
text_entry.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=(W,E))
ttk.Button(frame,text="Add songname",command=textMethod).grid(column=1,row=1)

songListFrame = Frame(frame, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)

frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

xscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E+W)

yscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
yscrollbar.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=N+S)

songList = Text(frame, wrap=NONE, bd=0,
            xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
            yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

songList.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

xscrollbar.config(command=songList.xview)
yscrollbar.config(command=songList.yview)

frame.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Added a newline to the line as well, so that each song comes in a new line .

Comment: Thank you very much, that was extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The Text widget doesn't use a text variable.  To read the text from the widget, use its get() method.  I recommend John Shipman's intro to tkinter at infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html

Comment: And an example: https://web.archive.org/web/20230131025032/https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-get-the-input-from-tkinter-text-box/